# PL/SQL Calculate sum of start/end dates difference

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum

I have a table with start and end dates of non-attendance and  i want to get the sum of days of absenteeism grouped by id and by month. I do this by calculating difference between dates +1. The problem is that sometimes dates periods overlap with each others. Here is an example:

```
ID   ABS_START    ABS_END        NBR_ABS

5    04/02/2016   04/02/2016         1
5    05/02/2016   05/02/2016         1
5    06/02/2016   07/02/2016         2
5    07/02/2016   20/02/2016         14
5    08/02/2016   14/02/2016         7

NBR_ABS = number of absences relative to dates period
```

Expected results:

```
ID   ABS_MONTH    NBR_ABS_MONTH

5    2016/02           17
6    2016/02           0
7    2016/02           5
8    2016/02           13
9    2016/02           2

NBRE_ABS_MONTH = number of absences by id for whole month
```

Is there any way to deal with such issue in oracle environment ?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: expected result please

Comment: How you are storing data ? And why you are storing data like this ? If there is already an entry from 7-Feb-2016 to 20-Feb-2016 what is need to make another entry from 8-Feb-2016 to 14-Feb-2016?

Comment: @Keyur Panchal I'm extracting raw data from database created by a foreigner. For one person, dates range are assigned to different types of absence labels (different contracts)

Comment: @XING & Vecchiasignora expected results edited.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to get a list of dates in a range and check.  For instance:

```
with dates as (
      select (date '2016-02-01') + rownum - 1 
      from all_objects 
      where rownum <= 29
     )
select i.id, count(*) as absence_201602
from dates cross join
     (select distinct id from t) i
where exists (select 1
              from t
              where t.id = i.id and
                    d.date between t.abs_start and t.abs_end
             )
group by id;
```

Comment: Instead of relying on all_objects, which has a limited number of rows (~73k here), I would use `select (date '2016-02-01') + rownum - 1 from dual connect by rownum<=29` where 29, the arbitrary limit, can be set as high as required. As long as days are in question, all_objects is probably big enough, but change that to hours and it might not.